# Insert and Modify two different table at the same time in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I want to update the field in my table, and insert some information about the user that login success in my web site in another table.
This is my code :

```
public class CustomerModels:ItemEntityDataContext
{

    public bool ValidateCustomer(string username, string password)
    {
        var user = this.DataContext.Customers
                                   .Where(s => s.ActiveInWebLogin == 1 &&
                                    s.WebAccount == username &&
                                    s.Password == password)
                                   .SingleOrDefault();

        if (user != null)
        {
            this.UpdateCustomerLastUpdateStatus(user);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }



    public void UpdateCustomerLastUpdateStatus(Customer c)
    {
        c.LastWebLogIn = DateTime.Now;

        String ipAddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

        WebsiteTracking web_track = new WebsiteTracking();
        web_track.IDUser = c.ID;
        web_track.ActiveLoginDate = DateTime.Now;
        web_track.IPAddress = ipAddress;

        this.DataContext.SaveChanges();


    }


}
```

When I wrote this, It is only modify the field LastWebLogIn in Customer table, but not insert to the field in table WebsiteTracking.

Anyone can solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add created `WebsiteTracking` to collection `this.DataContext.WebsiteTracking`. Other way is using `WebsiteTracking` property of your `User` object. Until you use one of them DataContext doesn't know anything about `web_track` object.

```
public void UpdateCustomerLastUpdateStatus(Customer c)
{
    c.LastWebLogIn = DateTime.Now;

    String ipAddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

    WebsiteTracking web_track = new WebsiteTracking();
    web_track.ActiveLoginDate = DateTime.Now;
    web_track.IPAddress = ipAddress;

    c.WebsiteTracking.Add(web_track);

    this.DataContext.SaveChanges();


}
```

Comment: web_track.User is not work because it doesn't contain a definition 'User' in my table.

Comment: OP says that `c` is updated, not created, so using `c.ID` should be fine.

Comment: It is error with yours at this line : c.WebsiteTracking.Add(web_track);

Answer (score 1):

To update object in Linq to SQL:

1. first access the object
2. update their values
3. Perform Context.SubmitChanges();

Check modified Code.
You can update multiple objects at time but you must take care about the foreign key relations/ or rules that object/Entity Class creates.

```
     public void UpdateCustomerLastUpdateStatus(Customer c)
        {
        using ( var context = new this.DataContext())  
    // if you have created object on page then it may no need to create object again for DataContext
        {

Customer cust = DataContext.Customer.Single(cu => cu.ID == c.ID);
// Validate cust that your Customer Id if it is supposed to be null reference issue.
cust.LastWebLogIn = DateTime.Now;

            String ipAddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

            WebsiteTracking web_track = new WebsiteTracking();
            web_track.ActiveLoginDate = DateTime.Now;
            web_track.IPAddress = ipAddress;

            cust.WebsiteTracking.Add(web_track);
            //or
            DataContext.WebsiteTracking.Add(web_track);

            this.DataContext.SaveChanges();
        }            

        }
```

Comment: it should work .. as you passing customer object then no need to access from database.. i think there may be some problem with the LInqtoSql File..  trace the error using break point in the entity class that you have created..